# Integration of two different jQueries

Tags: jquery

In my code listed below, jQuery is version 1.9.1 and jQuery1 is version 1.2.6, how will I be able to integrate both of them so that both will be compatible with each other?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Auto Complete Input box</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tag").autocomplete("autoCompleteMain.php", {
                    selectFirst: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Tag:</label>
            <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="20" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sometimes, you are working with a legacy version in an existing site (e.g. Wordpress) but you want a new version of jquery for a specific feature. This way you can leave the existing site unchanged but still use a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call jQuery more than once, that will cause errors. You can, however, assign jQuery to its own variable when you load it.

```
<script src="first/js/file.js"></script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Load second file..

From here on out you would use `$j` instead of the usual `$`

Use the first jQuery version...

```
$j('#someID').hide();
```

Use the second jQuery version:

```
$('#someID').show();
```

Comment: Not true. You can load it multiple times using noconflict.

Comment: Someone explain the down vote please?

Comment: @SteveP You got me before my edit ... check again :)

Comment: The first version of this answer was just *"You can't call jQuery more than once, that will cause errors."* That is just wrong, hence the downvote. That's the risk of playing the fastest gun in the west.

Comment: @Juhana good call - regardless, I put my guns down and fixed the issues.

Comment: @user2216351 what do you mean *it's not working* ?

Comment: @user2216351 you may want to load one file, declare the variable, *then* load the next.

Comment: Okay, I did already. Thanks :)